# Distance between two Partitions in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how to compute the Rand index between two partitions of the same universe in R.

Suppose my partitions are given as follows:

```
               fList <- list("1"=1:4, "2"=5:8, "3"=9:12, "4"=13:16, "5"=17:20)
               sList <- list("1"=1:6, "2"=7:9, "3"=10:12, "4"=13:16, "5"= 17:20)
```

I haven't managed to calculate the Rand index using cl_dissimilarity. I attempted the following to no avail:

```
cl_dissimilarity(as.cl_ensemble(fList), as.cl_ensemble(sList), method = "Rand")
```

EDIT: I just found a simple way to complete the task at hand:

```
library(clues)

fVector <- c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4), rep(5,4))
sVector <- c(rep(1,6), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,4), rep(5,4))

adjustedRand(fVector, sVector, randMethod="Rand")
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right format? I would say you need rep(1,4), rep(2,4), ... and so on all in one vector.

Comment: Your suggestion does not seem to work.